# Consuming io.Source iterator conditionally

Tags: scala, iterator

I'd like to read a file with `scala.io.Source` in chunks conditionally, so after I processed the chunk, I can continue reading later from the same place.

Suppose I have a file with 10 lines with numbers from 0 to 9, then I can achieve my goal with the following:

```scala
import scala.io.Source

class Reader(filePath: String) {
    var src = Source.fromFile(filePath).getLines
    def get(f: String => Boolean) = {
        val (a, b) = src.span(f)
        src = b
        a
    }
}

object Reader {
    def apply(filePath: String) = new Reader(filePath)
}

val file = Reader("file")

val res1 = file.get(_.toInt < 5).toList
// List("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")
val res2 = file.get(_.toInt < 10).toList
// List("5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
```

Can I do any better, without mutating the source e.g.?

**EDIT**

I've seen comments suggesting `takeWhile` on Iterator. Note, this doesn't work for a good reason (see implementation of `takeWhile` on Iterator):

```
val it = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).iterator
val res1 = it.takeWhile(_<5).toList
// List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val res2 = it.takeWhile(_<10).toList
// List(6, 7, 8, 9), 5 is missing
```

this is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: ``` val lines = Source.fomFile(...).getLines(); val res1 = lines.take(5).toSeq; val res2 = lines.take(10).toSeq``` 

Comment: @Dima I need to take conditionally, not in chunks with predefined sizes

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "predefined". You can use any size ...

Comment: I do not know the size in advance, I need to take while condition holds

Comment: `lines.takeWhile(condition)` ?

Comment: How do you define the condition? Your example looks as if each next call could have a different predicate. How many of these would there be? Fixed amount? Generated from external source? Generated from previous result? Without that information it's hard to tell what kind of API you would need as your example relies on mutability without showing why it has to rely on it.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The example of call is in the Edit. Each next time we are supplying a different increasing number, each next time we have to consume everything less than that number (which will be actually not a number, rather an id of an array if that matters).  The number of calls is unknown in advance, until the iterator is exhausted, depends on the contents of the file and ids supplied from external logic. And the iterator is sorted. Please ask more if something is not clear.

Comment: "*Can I do any better*" Please edit the question to clarify, in objective terms, what you mean by "better".

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator` is mutable and as long as you use it you will have mutations. At best you could hide working with `var`s and similar from the API and hide it inside some method which tries to provide as sane API as possible.

If you sill want to use `Iterator` (and acknowledge that consuming element is a side effect, and once it's consumed it's gone) then you can try something like this:

```
def splitIntoChunks(it: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[Iterator[Int]] = {
  import scala.util.chaining.*

  var lastOpt: Option[Int] = None
  def withCutoff(cutoff: Int): (Iterator[Int], Int) = {
    val newIterator = lastOpt.iterator ++ it
      .map(_.tap(a => lastOpt = Some(a)))
      .takeWhile(_ < cutoff) // <- no idea how you want to update value
                             //    define this part yourself
    lastOpt = None
    newIterator -> cutoff
  }  

  Iterator
    .iterate(withCutoff(5)) { case (_, oldCutoff) =>
      withCutoff(oldCutoff + 5)
    }
    .map(_._1)
    .takeWhile(_ => it.hasNext)
}

splitIntoChunks(Iterator(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15))
  .foreach { iterator =>
    println(iterator.mkString(", "))
  }
```

(see [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qbqP6ziCRxW01ZModrsgZg)).

If all the data were loaded in memory (if they would fit into memory) you could create a `List` of values at first, and then work with some `foldLeft` or iterating with `take`+`drop` to group data into chunks (although there aren't many cases of grouping data into chunks if we already loaded them all in memory).

For truly pure approach you'd have to use something like [FS2 library](https://fs2.io/#/io?id=files) instead of `Source` and `Iterator` as these are simple abstractions, quite OK for scripting and small snippets, but not necessarily for enterprise application development with pure FP requirements. Although it would be quite a leap if someone haven't used IO and reactive streams before.

Answer (score 1):

I used `span` to create a function that does this:

```
def chunkBy[A](it: Iterator[A])(p: A => Boolean): Iterator[Iterator[A]] =
  if (!it.hasNext) Iterator.empty
  else {
    val (chunk, rest) = it.span(p)
    Iterator.single(chunk) ++ chunkBy(rest)(p)
  }
```

Using a mutable variable to keep track of the last reached item, it can be used as follows (while it's not ideal, if you need/want to use a mutable `Iterator`, it might make sense):

```
val ns = List.range(1, 10) // end is exclusive
val gap = 4
var next = gap

for (chunk <- chunkBy(ns.iterator)(_ <= next)) {
  val indexedChunk = chunk.toVector
  next = indexedChunk.last + gap
  println(indexedChunk.mkString(", "))
}
```

This prints the following:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/T4SEFoFoR6uONbTm6WxEWQ/13).

Note that the implementations of `++` ensures that `chunkBy` retrieves items lazily, which is probably what you want.